# Issues with Perl script and date concatenation removal/file rename

Tags: string, perl, file-io

So, I am trying to rename excel files like "test_09182009.xlsx" to "test.xlsx" and would like to overwrite the file if it already exists. This was working for me on my local machine or so I thought but doesn't seem to be working with a network directory at all. Anyone have any ideas?

```
my $sourceDir = "\\networkPath\;

opendir ( DIR, $sourceDir );

foreach my $fileName (readdir(DIR)) 
{


    if (index($fileName, '_') != -1) 
    {
        rename($fileName, substr($fileName,0,index($fileName, '_')).".xlsx");
    } 
}
closedir(DIR);
```

So I think I have it isolated to when the script is not in the working directory of the file being renamed. Is there a way to specify that with rename parameters?

Comment: Is this running in Windows?

Comment: You're not checking the return value of `opendir`. If you did, you'd probably see that it's returning an error.

Answer (score 2):

One of the things that people always find confusing about `readdir` (and equivalents in other languages) is that it only returns file names within a directory.  It does not return paths to files.  So if you are in `/home/example` and you call `readdir` on `/tmp/example` that contains files `a` and `b`, what you get back from `readdir` is just `a`, not `/tmp/example/a`.

In general, whenever you use the results of `readdir`, you need to either qualify the file with the directory name or change directories to the directory that you're calling `readdir` on.

In this specific case, add:

```
my $filePath = $sourceDir . $fileName;
```

to the top of your loop (I assume that `$sourceDir` has a trailing backslash in your actual code; the code you pasted doesn't actually close the quote) and then act on `$filePath`, not `$fileName`.  (You will need to tweak this answer if the `$sourceDir` can contain an underscore; in that case, you may want to generate the transformed file name first and then qualify them both with `$sourceDir` before doing the rename.)

Answer (score 0):

Try using forward slashes instead of backslashes.  Such as

```
my $sourceDir = "//networkPath/";
```

That was worked with Active Perl in our Windows environment.